# Form data autosuggestion

Tags: javascript

I have a button( Add More) which adds new row in my form/table. I want to add data autosuggestion in INPUT form. so i've tried the below codes. It's working but only for first row. It's not working for the next rows. can anyone correct me what i a doing wrong? You can check it in my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh7ebfxx/1/) too .

```
<table class="table" id="dataTable" name="table">
 <TD><INPUT type="text" id="tags" /></TD>
</table> 
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">Add More</button>

/*** Form autosuggestion **/
$(function() {
 var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",   
  ];
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});

/*** Adding new row **/
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        if(i==1){newcell.innerHTML = (rowCount+1)}
        else{
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
           }
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                    break;
            case "test":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value="";
                    break;
            case "checkbox":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                    break;
            case "select-one":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is not working is because you have passed same id for two text fields, and in HTML you can't have duplicate ids as it doesn't make sense.

here you can do two things

1. Give class to new element and get element from class
2. Or when you create an element at that time create a autosuggest object for that field

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh7ebfxx/8/) for you

**HTML CODE:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table class="table" id="dataTable" name="table">
  <TD>
    <INPUT type="text" id="tags" class="autosuggest" />
  </TD>
</table>

<br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
    Add More
</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
 function createAutoSuggest(element) { // Created a common function for you
   var availableTags = [
     "ActionScript",
     "AppleScript",
     "Asp",
     "BASIC",
     "C",
     "C++",
     "Clojure",
     "COBOL",
     "ColdFusion",
   ];
   $(element).autocomplete({
     source: availableTags
   });
 }
 $(function() {

   createAutoSuggest($(".autosuggest"));
 });

 function addRow(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
   var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

   for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
     var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
     if (i == 1) {
       newcell.innerHTML = (rowCount + 1)
     } else {
       newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
     }

     switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
       case "text":
         newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
         break;
       case "test":
         newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
         break;
       case "checkbox":
         newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
         break;
       case "select-one":
         newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
         break;
     }

     if ($(newcell).find('.autosuggest').length > 0) {
       createAutoSuggest($(newcell).find('.autosuggest'));// This is the change you basically need
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Would you write few line of code for me? i got you but don't know how to do that. i am newbie in javascript.

Comment: @Nazmul: Updated the answer, have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use live to attach events to dynamically created textboxes.
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6mtYe/)

Comment: Just to let you know ".live" is deprecated  .. you can read it more .. http://api.jquery.com/live/